# Search Actionview not collapsing in single up button click android actionbar compat

Tags: android, search, android-actionbar-compat

I am using actionbar compat support library to provide search widget in Action Bar. The search action view is collapsing only after pressing back button or up button twice. I had same problem while executing the sample dictionary search also.

Code in my search activity which extends ActionBarActivity

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

        // Find the search item
        MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

My Searchable.xml looks like this

```
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:label="@string/search_label"
    android:hint="@string/search_hint"
    android:voiceSearchMode="showVoiceSearchButton|launchRecognizer"
    >
```

Let me know if any more information needed...

Comment: You need to add significantly more information for there to be any hope of a solution being found. We need to see code.

Comment: @PatrickDattilio I have added more information bro..

Answer (score 0):

Check the API guide http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#ActionView This is what it should look for anything less than API 11.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >
<item 
android:id="@+id/action_search"
android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
yourapp:orderInCategory="9"
yourapp:menuCategory="system"
yourapp:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
yourapp:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
android:title="@string/action_searchSt" />
</menu>
```

That's probably more attributes than you need (*menuCategory* and *orderInCategory* are unnecessary). But assuming you've added in the support library correctly and you read the link I gave, things should work as intended.